# ignore merges in a git diff

Tags: git, git-merge

I want to do a git diff from a tag which is ignoring merges in his branch.
Let explain what I want with a simple example

```
#                               ~+A                             git diff running here                                                                                                                                                                       
#Branch B ______________________|_____________________________________|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#                       |       ^           |       |                                                                                                                                                                           
#                       +Z      |           +Y      |                                                                                                                                                                                   
#                       tag1    |merge A            Merge B                                                                                                                                                                             
#                               |in B               |in A                                                                                                                                                                                           
#                               |                   |                                                                                                                                                                                   
#Branch A ______________________|___________________v_____________________                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#               |                                   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#               +A                                  ~+Z
```

In this case I want to be able to have the diff in the branch B, until the tag1

```
git diff tag1
```

The problem is that I will have in this git diff

```
+A
+Y
```

I only want the +Y because I want that my git diff ignore the merging of A in B

even if I create a temporary branch in the branch B this solution seems to not work because I merge A in B and B in A.

Please let me know if you already had this issue or if you have a good idea to solve it.

Comment: I don't see tag1 in your diagram.

Comment: I just add it. It's with the commit +Z

Answer (score 2):

You can get there using the `--first-parent` and `--no-merges` flags of `git-log(1)`:

Command:

```
user@machine$ git log --no-merges --first-parent --patch-with-stat tag1..HEAD
```

Output:

```
commit cff05df7d5a91d555c8c848b71a384b5048aa8f8
Author: Barend <email hidden>
Date:   Fri Oct 9 21:15:25 2015 +0200

    Y message
---
 Y | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. It is actually working well. The only problem is that I need to use a git diff because I don't want to have all the history of commits. I just want to know what is new.
If no other solutions exist I will try to run a script to transform this git log in a git diff 
In this case your solution will be really helpfull for me :)